# Control line space

Tags: pysimplegui

Hi How can we control the line space? It seems we can only adjust font

For example, how can I make 'my name' 'is' closer to each other without changing the font?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [
    [sg.pin(sg.T('Hello'))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('my name'))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('is'))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('Mike'))],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

Comment: You can use sg.Text with pad=(0,0) property for 'my name' or any other pad

Comment: Doesn't pad make line space bigger? I want to make it smaller

Answer (score 1):

> param pad
>
> Amount of padding to put around element in pixels (left/right, top/bottom) or ((left, right), (top, bottom)) or an int. If an int, then it's converted into a tuple (int, int)
>
> type pad
>
> (int, int) or ((int, int),(int,int)) or (int,(int,int)) or  ((int, int),int) | int

Default pad value is `sg.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_PADDING, (5, 3)`, give option `pad` for the element if you want different padding.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.pin(sg.T('Hello'))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('my name', pad=(5, (10, 0))))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('is', pad=(5, (0, 10))))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T('Mike'))],
]

sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a font parameter to the Text element. You can also add a size parameter to make the text larger or smaller if you want.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.pin(sg.T("Hello", font=("Helvetica", 20)))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T("my name", font=("Helvetica", 20)))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T("is", font=("Helvetica", 20)))],
    [sg.pin(sg.T("Mike", font=("Helvetica", 20)))],
]

window = sg.Window("Hello World", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: What I want is to make line space smaller, so there is no space in between hello and my name or space is smaller than 'is' and 'Mike' for example. If I change 'my name' font to 10, it can't do what I wanted